# TypeScript: How do I call a member function from another function?

Tags: typescript, this

I am trying to call a member function from another member function - and failing. I figured this would be easy to find but after 10 minutes of searching I can't find what's wrong here.

In the following code (and yes I know pausecomp is a big no-no, I'm just trying to test against a possible race condition):

```
class LayoutWorker {
    /*
     Specific events handlers.
     e is the object sent by the client. See events.layout for object definitions.
     */
    handlers = {
        textadd: function (e) {
            for (var ind=0; ind<10; ind++)
            {
                console.log("entering textadd = " + e);
                // Do the work and call the client back if needed. You can pass to the client any object.
                e.text += " -- Hello back from the worker!";
                postClientMessage(e);

                this.pausecomp(4000);
            }
        },

        urgent: function (e) {
            for (var ind=0; ind<10; ind++)
            {
                console.log("entering urgent = " + e);
                // Do the work and call the client back if needed. You can pass to the client any object.
                e.text += " -- Hello back from the worker!";
                postClientMessage(e);

                this.pausecomp(1000);
            }
        }

    };

    handleEvent(e) {
        console.log("entering handleEvent = " + e);
        // Call the specific handler.
        this.handlers[e.id](e);
    }

    pausecomp(millis : number) : void
    {
        var date = new Date();
        var curDate = new Date();
        while(curDate - date < millis)
            curDate = new Date();
    }
}
```

When I run the above I get:
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'pausecomp'

What do I have wrong?

thanks - dave

Comment: Examien what the value of `this` is inside your event handler. You'll be surprised, I think. It's not what you think.

Comment: @x0n Unfortunately I have not yet been able to get either Chrome or WebStorm to break on breakpoints in my worker thread. Once I get that working then I can do this.

Comment: Really? You can force it by placing the javascript keyword `debugger` in the handler.

Comment: @xOn I tried that - doesn't work with either. I think both of them have "issues" with breaking in a worker thread.

Comment: To understand `this` a bit better in TypeScript : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA&hd=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `handlers` object, `this` refers to `handlers`, not the class instance.

A reduced version:

```
class MyClass {
    handlers = {
        name: 'handlers',
        foo() {
            console.log(this.name);
        }
    }

    name = 'MyClass';

}

var x = new MyClass();
x.handlers['foo'](); // Prints 'handlers', not 'MyClass';
```

My recommendation would be to pass the class instance to the handler functions as an additional argument, or even better to just refactor this pattern entirely. As written it doesn't really make sense -- you're creating a new `handlers` object for every instance of the class, even though they belong on the prototype (because they don't hold instance data).

Answer (score 7):

In your example, `this` refers to the function of `handler`. You could also use a lambda expression (`() =>`) or an instance function (`foo() {}`).

If you're using a lambda, `this` should refer to `MyClass`. Here are some options for defining a class instance function: http://bit.ly/1ep5dMk

Because `handlers` is a seperate class with members for it's own, it cannot refer to LayoutWorker - unless you use a lambda.

You've got 3 options:

- pass an instance of `LayoutWorker` somewhere
- declare the `pausecomp` method as `public` and `static` and use `LayoutWorker.pausecomp(arg)` to call.
- use a lambda (see examples of the TypeScript playground)

I created a little overview of the 3 mentioned options:
http://bit.ly/1kOeWtS

Some recommendation:

Define a handler interface and/or seperate classes to get a clearer view of your class model. This helps understanding that `this` cannot refer to the LayoutWorker.